# Как убрать пробелы в data-scroll PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

подскажите пожалуйста, как тут в первом data-scroll(где $content) удалить пробелы. Якорь не вешается когда заголовок состоит больше чем из одного слова.

```
<div class="sidebar col-sm-3">
        <div class="lineOfBusines">
            <?php

            $content .= "<ul class=\"ul-sidebar\">";
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $content .= "<li><a href='#' data-scroll=\"$tag->tag_name\">$tag->tag_name</a></li>";
            }
            $content .= "</ul>";
            echo $content;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block" class=" wrapper-media col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

        <?php
            foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
                <div><a href="#" class="tag_name" data-scroll="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tag->tag_name); ?>"><?php echo $tag->tag_name; ?></a></div>

                <?php

                // get posts by tag and category
                $posts = get_posts_by_tag_and_category($tag->tag_slug,$taxonomy->slug);

                ?>
```

Comment: подменить пробелы на +

Comment: Но это заголовок, он выводиться на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как-нибудь так

```
<?php
$content .= "<ul class=\"ul-sidebar\">";
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $data_scroll = str_replace(' ', '', $tag->tag_name);
    $content .= "<li><a href='#' data-scroll=\"$data_scroll\">$tag->tag_name</a></li>";
}
$content .= "</ul>";
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)) Я так же пробовала но не правильно синтаксис писала.(str_replace(' ', '', ...вот здесь) Я не безнадежна))